# Java for loop not incrementing

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

```
BufferedReader inputStream = null;
    String fileLine;
    int employeeCount = 1;
    String[] years = new String[2];
    //Employee[] employees = new Employee[employeeCount + 1];
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    File myFile = new File("src/project1/data.txt");
    //System.out.println("Attempting to read from file in: "+ myFile.getCanonicalPath());
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            String[] data = strLine.split(" ");
            //while ( int i < employees.length ) {
            for (int i=1; i < employees.size(); i++ ) {
                if (data[1].equals("Executive")) {
                    employees.add( new Executive(data[0],data[1],data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3]), Integer.parseInt(data[4])) );
                } else if (data[1].equals("Salesman")) {
                    employees.add( new Salesman(data[0],data[1],data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3]), Integer.parseInt(data[4])) );
                } else {
                    employees.add( new Employee(data[0],data[1],data[2], Integer.parseInt(data[3])) );
                }
                //System.out.println(employees[i].toString());
                System.out.println(i +" " + employeeCount);
                employeeCount++;
            }
        }
        for (int y=1; y < employees.size(); y++ ) {
            System.out.println(employees.get(y).getName());
        }
        //System.out.println(employees.toString());
    } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println("File IO exception" + io.getMessage());
    }
```

`EmployeeCount` is incrementing as expected, but `i` is always 1 - what am I missing here? textfile is read in line by line using a while loop - for loop checks if second piece of data matches a string and creates object base on match. Am I making sense here?

Comment: Why are you combining a for loop and a while loop? Likely employees.length remains 1.

Comment: Your "if" clauses all use `data[1]`, with the number 1, not the variable i. I think that's what's causing your problems.

Comment: @yshavit: I like your comment better than mine. Sharp eyes.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop should probably be `for (int i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) `, starting at `0` and looping over `data`. However, this assumes that `employees` is large enough. Maybe you should use a `List<Employee>` instead.

Comment: what is the initial value of 'employeeCount'  ??

Comment: could you provide some line from your text file?

Comment: Also, what is that inner for loop for? It seems you are just adding the same employee to the list i times.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop is not incrementing because the condition is false after the first iteration at:

```
for (int i=1; i < employees.length; i++ ) {
```

that is, `employees.length` is 2 since `employeeCount` was one at this line (I must assume that since the code is incomplete):

```
Employee[] employees = new Employee[employeeCount + 1];
```

This line creates an array with two positions since `employeeCount + 1` was 2. The size is **not** automatically adjusted as `employeeCount` is incremented...

I suggest using a List instead of an array, since the List is expanded as needed:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
...
employees.add(new Employee(...));
```